# xslt code to loop cdata segment in my map

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my xslt code to get the cdata segment values and send to destination

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0 s1" version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://AIS/IL/ES/QueryROCNoResp/JIM/v1.0" xmlns:s0="http://ws.myimm.htp.com/" xmlns:s1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="s1:Envelope">
  <ns0:response>
    <item>      
        <result>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;result>'), '&lt;/result>')"/>
        </result>
        <name>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;name>'), '&lt;/name>')"/>
        </name>
        <ppt_no>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;ppt_no>'), '&lt;/ppt_no>')"/>
        </ppt_no>
        <nat_cd>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;nat_cd>'), '&lt;/nat_cd>')"/>
        </nat_cd>
        <dob>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;dob>'), '&lt;/dob>')"/>
        </dob>
        <sex_cd>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;sex_cd>'), '&lt;/sex_cd>')"/>
        </sex_cd>
        <ppt_exp_dt>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;ppt_exp_dt>'), '&lt;/ppt_exp_dt>')"/>
        </ppt_exp_dt>
        <pas_apprv_dt>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;pas_apprv_dt>'), '&lt;/pas_apprv_dt>')"/>
        </pas_apprv_dt>
        <pas_expry_dt>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;pas_expry_dt>'), '&lt;/pas_expry_dt>')"/>
        </pas_expry_dt>
        <vp_no>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;vp_no>'), '&lt;/vp_no>')"/>
        </vp_no>
        <sector>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;sector>'), '&lt;/sector>')"/>
        </sector>
        <ref_no>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;ref_no>'), '&lt;/ref_no>')"/>
        </ref_no>   
      </item>
    </ns0:response>  
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input File:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:incomingResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.myimm.htp.com/">
         <return>
         <![CDATA[
            <response>
                <item>
                    <result>1</result>
                    <name>PINOKIO</name>
                    <ppt_no>001FILIPINA</ppt_no>
                    <nat_cd>PHL</nat_cd>
                    <dob>19800101</dob>
                    <sex_cd>2</sex_cd>
                    <ppt_exp_dt>20150116</ppt_exp_dt>
                    <pas_apprv_dt>20130619</pas_apprv_dt>
                    <pas_expry_dt>20160718</pas_expry_dt>
                    <vp_no>P1401219062013110321374</vp_no>
                    <sector>PA</sector>
                    <ref_no>BPR/14012/CFATL0449374</ref_no>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <result>1</result>
                    <name>LIN SHU YUAN</name>
                    <ppt_no>210139660</ppt_no>
                    <nat_cd>TWN</nat_cd>
                    <dob>19631001</dob>
                    <sex_cd>2</sex_cd>
                    <ppt_exp_dt>20130930</ppt_exp_dt>
                    <pas_apprv_dt>20031203</pas_apprv_dt>
                    <pas_expry_dt>20160718</pas_expry_dt>
                    <vp_no>150406</vp_no>
                    <sector>PA</sector>
                    <ref_no>150406</ref_no>
                </item>
            </response>
            ]]>
            </return>
      </ns2:incomingResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Output:

My output should be like

```
<ns0:records xmlns:ns0="http://AIS/IL/ES/QueryROCNoReq/JIM/v1.0">
<item>
                    <result>1</result>
                    <name>PINOKIO</name>
                    <ppt_no>001FILIPINA</ppt_no>
                    <nat_cd>PHL</nat_cd>
                    <dob>19800101</dob>
                    <sex_cd>2</sex_cd>
                    <ppt_exp_dt>20150116</ppt_exp_dt>
                    <pas_apprv_dt>20130619</pas_apprv_dt>
                    <pas_expry_dt>20160718</pas_expry_dt>
                    <vp_no>P1401219062013110321374</vp_no>
                    <sector>PA</sector>
                    <ref_no>BPR/14012/CFATL0449374</ref_no>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <result>1</result>
                    <name>LIN SHU YUAN</name>
                    <ppt_no>210139660</ppt_no>
                    <nat_cd>TWN</nat_cd>
                    <dob>19631001</dob>
                    <sex_cd>2</sex_cd>
                    <ppt_exp_dt>20130930</ppt_exp_dt>
                    <pas_apprv_dt>20031203</pas_apprv_dt>
                    <pas_expry_dt>20160718</pas_expry_dt>
                    <vp_no>150406</vp_no>
                    <sector>PA</sector>
                    <ref_no>150406</ref_no>
                </item>
</ns0:records>
```

I tried using for each but it fails to provide proper output.How to achieve this using xslt.Can someone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not work for you, depending upon your processor support of `disable-output-escaping`. However, it's worth a try because it's significantly simpler than parsing the CDATA section for each individual element as you tried.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:records xmlns:ns0="http://AIS/IL/ES/QueryROCNoReq/JIM/v1.0">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(//return, '&lt;/response&gt;'), '&lt;response&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </ns0:records>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```